# Typescript Unresolved function

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript 0.9.1.1 and I seem to be getting an error with this simple problem:

```
function doSomething(): void {
    console.log("Printing something");
}

window.setTimeout(() => {
    doSomething();
}, 3000);
```

It says that I have an `Unresolved Function or Method setTimeOut()`. I looked into the Typescript lib.d.ts file, and this is what I found:

```
declare function setTimeout(expression: any, msec?: number, language?: any): number;
```

From [this piece of documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout), I can also say that I am calling it right. So, why is TypeScript giving me issues?

This is what my lib.d.ts file looks like:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Compiles fine on the playground. http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=function%20doSomething()%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Printing%20something%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Awindow.setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%3B%0A%7D%2C%203000)%3B

Comment: It compiles for me too, but it gives me an error nonetheless.

Comment: Check out eap http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+7+EAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using 0.9.1.1 and the signature is different to the one you have posted:

```
declare function setTimeout(handler: any, timeout?: any, ...args: any[]): number;
```

And everything compiles fine to:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("Printing something");
}

window.setTimeout(function () {
    doSomething();
}, 3000);
```

Where are you looking for that lib.d.ts?

In any case, you shouldn't get the error because the signature you posted only requires the expression (any) and you are supplying an msec (number) of the correct type - so your call looks compatible with that.

Comment: Thanks for this man. It seems that my IDE, Webstorm has its own version of `lib.d.ts`. Man, sometimes IDEs can be more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you through this. I use webstorm, but I think from now on, I will change my IDE.

Comment: I think WebStorm might be using an older version of TypeScript - should all iron out when they update the language services.

Comment: Well, I'm using Webstorm 7 EAP.